# Как сделать чтобы поле ENUM заполнялось данными из справочника?

Tags: mysql

**Используется:**
   - MySQL - 5.7

Имеется несколько таблиц, в которых есть поле типа **ENUM**.
Данные для подстановки в поле во всех таблицах одинаковые.

**Вопрос.**
Как сделать, чтобы данные для подстановки в поля типа **ENUM** использовались из одного источника?
Т.е. все таблицы используют один справочник.

**НАПРИМЕР**
**Таблица осн**

```
CREATE TABLE `tst_001_tb_00` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `pl_1_txt` TEXT NULL,
    `pl_2_enum` ENUM('Y','N') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    INDEX `id` (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
;
```

**Таблица СПРАВОЧНИК**

```
CREATE TABLE `tst_001_tb_01_sprch` (
    `pl_2_enum` TEXT NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
;
```

Comment: сделать foreign key поля enum на таблицу с  данными

Comment: @BogdanK Добавил пример таблиц в вопрос... Если вам не сложно покажите на примере приведённых мной таблиц.. А  то, что-то не получается

Comment: заведите отдельную таблицу-справочник. в ней каждому значению "enum" даете id и в таблицах поле уже объявляете не enum, а простой int, но дополнительно добавляете foreign key указывающий на справочник.